# iOS multiple screen not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I just started iOS programming and I want to make a login screen. I want to align center horizontally the everything on all devices like the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus but it's not working. I just put the elements on the screen. Anything else i need to do?

[image]

Comment: You should constrain your UI elements using Autolayout.

Comment: You should first learn about [autolayouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1), also there are tons of tutorials available.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this...auto layout as @ozgur said is your friend.

what I would do is throw them into a **Stack View**

To do that tap each horizontal group so for example "username" label AND the text field to the right and while they are both selected tap the icon at the bottom right that is on the left of the 4 icons (it has a downward arrow)...now do the same for the password...now do the same for the login button...now select all 3 stackviews and tap stackview again...

NOW....on the left navigation select the topmost stackview and then again on the bottom this time tap the small icon to the right of the stackview button...to make it simple and in the center tap horizontally in container and vertically in container then add the 2 constraints....

you will also need a height and width so now once more with the whole thing selected tap the |o| looking icon to the right...now give it the height and width you like but before you tap add 2 contraints at the bottom of that menu is a drop down menu..tap it and select "update all frames in container"

that should do it

Comment: there is a lot you can do with the stack views now by the way....within each inner stack view (by that i mean NOT the main containing stackview) you can set the spacing a few different ways...more than happy to keep assisting if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoLayOut Constraints to fix your issue.
Contraints will set the spacing with the view.You have to apply it on every single element of your view.

if you only want every thing in center no different spacing for different iPhone use stack View. it will provide the best solution for you.
stackView means collection of your objects. it act as group of your elements so only apply constraints to your stackview.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb is to use Stack views and then use auto layout. Just put the Username and the text field in a stack view (horizontal stack view), same for the other) and then apply necessary spacing and/or autolayout constraints.

You need to learn how to work with Autolayout (I read you just started) and it could be hard concept to grasp at first (it was for me at least) but with practice, you'll master it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use the stack view, you need to learn auto layout and size class for adapting the screen.

auto layout began in iOS 6, sizeclass began in iOS 8.

Here is the official apple documentation, to study it. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/